# Proposed new workflow for Help & Improvement

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, help-improvement

From my memory, H&I has a few things that should be touched upon:

- [Handling trash that Triage sends there incorrectly](/q/291741/6388243)
- [Handling spotless questions that Triage sends there incorrectly](/q/339462/6388243)
- [Handling questions that require edits *from the author*](/q/346052/6388243)
- Handling reviewers that make trivial edits just to get to the badge
- Reviewers are imperfect and can miss things
- [No way of generating audits](/q/297420/6388243)

I've thought about it for a bit, and came up with the following overhaul of the current system:

- 3 actions: Looks OK, Edit, and Requires OP Edit.

  - Looks OK would be for questions that have nothing left to edit. Questions would leave the queue after receiving 3 Looks OK reviews, rather than a single Edit review. This way, if a reviewer misses something or makes a trivial edit, the edits needed will still be made, and if Triage sends in a good post in error, it won't hang around in the queue forever.
  - Edit would be the current Edit action in H&I, enhanced editor still included.
  - Requires OP Edit would leave an auto-comment prompting them to edit their question in a certain way, e.g. add an MCVE or clarify their intent. This would cast a close vote if the reviewer has the privileges necessary.
- Audits!

  - Take a post that a ♦ moderator and/or someone with 2000+ edits has made extensive changes to outside of code, show the reviewer the revision before that, and expect a review of Edit.
  - Take a post closed as off-topic or unclear (similar to a known-bad audit in Close Votes), and expect a review of Requires OP Edit.
  - Not entirely sure how to choose Looks OK audits.

Since I'm positive that I haven't just come up with a system that good in 2 hours, what would be the possible flaws with this? Things I could improve?

Comment: For the sake of argument if you use "this was later edited by reliable people into good shape" as Edit audits, nothing stops you from using the post-edit shape for Looks OK.

Comment: Given we can't get the help text for _Requires Editing_ changed, I don't think Triage/H&I is even on the company's priority list, much less near the top of it.